# calculating convolution of multinomial distribution

Tags: java, r, matlab, statistics

I'm doing a simulation where I need to calculate a [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions) of [multinomial distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).

Is there a library for doing this?  Preferably, I would like to be able to calculate exactly when the number of random variables are small and approximate when it gets larger.

The simulation code is in Java but I'm open to other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from MATLAB, you have the commands:

**mnrnd** (to generate multinomial random distribution)
http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/mnrnd.html

and

**conv** (to convolve two arrays)
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/conv.html